# A word for making idols from the dead ( Deadolatry ?)

Tags: single-word-requests

Edit : To those who think this is a loaded question, it is based on historical facts. If you can please share your unloaded equivalent version of the question that would preserve the factual information, that would be great.

What is a word for turning dead into idols , e.g. making shrines to them.
It was something that was happening during the dark ages in Europe, where a bone was attributed to a Saint was used to make shrines/churches.
The Arabs after invading countries had a similar setup, where they forced the local populous to make shrines for their dead Arab invaders and ask them for miracles and healing ( A practice that is still going on at least in Iran ). The best word I can think to describe this is deadolatry  ( Dead Idolatry )

Comment: A related phrase might be "ancestor worship".

Comment: Yeah, this is generally referred to as "ancestor worship".

Comment: @HotLicks The Arab invaders were not ancestors of the people in that region, nor the saints in most cases were ancestors of the people being fooled into the worshiping them.

Comment: Wow this is a loaded question.

Comment: If the Dead Invaders endured martyrdom, then martyrolatry, veneration of martyrs, would be the word to use. If the shrines were being set up to holy men, and in the hope of miracles, then hagiolatry is the dictionary word.

Comment: @BlessedGeek : please share your unloaded version of this question, I'll use that if it is still conveys the same information.

Comment: @Hugh : And what if the shrines were set up to mentally bind populous into submission to invaders? To repackage the dead invaders into holy one's and forced into mind of the people? Then what is the word that would describe that type of brain washing?

Comment: The worship of saints is called hagiolatry.

Comment: Before this question moves on, what do those of you more educated than me think about the pyramids of Giza and the pharaohs enshrined within them? Is this an example or just an ostentatious tomb?

Comment: Arjang, your a little close to this one, it seems. That's how the Nazis rolled and the early Jesuits.

Comment: @StuW :  Pyramids were just tombs, iirc historically the dead Pharaohs were not worsipped or asked for miracles/healing. Many tombs were hidden so that they were not disturbed in afterlife. In the cases related to my question, the places were/are advertised to drum up pilgrims and raise donations from them and keep local populous ignorant and superstitious delibretly.

Comment: @StuW : I kow natzis used works of some great poeple to drum up business for themselves, but I dont know about them setting up Natzi Saints for poeple to worship! what is good to google in this regard? I already know about Thules from Supernatural https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thule_Society , is that what you mean?

Comment: Hitler's philosophy was based on the Master Race. The 20 or so German soldiers killed in the blitzkrieg of Poland were "spiritual leaders." It was pure propaganda aimed at desensitizing Germans, split evenly between Catholic and Lutheran (or thereabouts), to the moral implications of senseless slaughter and domination. The Jews were "willing participants in the war effort," for instance. It was a religion in and of itself with Hitler as it's head. His defined authority was beyond the Pope and as perhaps a handservant of God. He expected obedience and worship as of a "lesser god."

Comment: @StuW : It seems the necrolatry machinery was in motion long before Hitler, immoral regimes put it into use to use to induce obedience by manufacturing superstition and blind obedience. It is something that is visibly missing in advanced nations , and visibly present in backward nations eg north korea.. Now that i have a name for this can look it up in histry and philosophy and as means of a political too used by immoral regimes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The word you're looking for is [**necrolatry**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/necrolatry).

Comment: Nice that this comes from a user called "dead". :P

Comment: @Scimonster : also the original suggested word was Deadolatry.

Comment: I would think this is used in a broader sense, not with physical relics of the dead, as described here. I find no definitions that support the use of this term in reference to objects from the dead, but rather of the essence of the dead person(s)... Closer to a formal term for "ancestor worship".

Answer (score 4):

Which term to use depends on the attitude you want to express. The first term I thought of was [ancestor worship](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ancestor%20worship):

> the custom of venerating deceased ancestors who are considered still a
>   part of the family and whose spirits are believed to have the power to
>   intervene in the affairs of the living

(Merriam Webster)

This word is relatively neutral, although it might have a negative connotation to some people (usually a negative sense would arise from an implicit religious assumption that only God is worthy of "worship").

However, Wikipedia's article about this practice is called ["Veneration of the dead,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veneration_of_the_dead) and it includes the following section discussing terminology:

> Most cultures who practice ancestor veneration do not call it
>   "ancestor worship." In English, the word worship usually refers to the
>   reverent love and devotion accorded a deity (god) or God.
>   However, in other cultures, this act of worship does not confer any
>   belief that the departed ancestors have become some kind of deity.
>   Rather, the act is a way to respect, honor and look after ancestors in
>   their afterlives as well as seek their guidance for their living
>   descendants. In this regard, many cultures and religions have similar
>   practices. Some may visit the graves of their parents or other
>   ancestors, leave flowers and pray to them in order to honor and
>   remember them, while also asking their ancestors to continue to look
>   after them. However, this would not be considered as worshipping them
>   since the term worship shows no such meaning.
>
> In that sense the phrase ancestor veneration may convey a more
>   accurate sense of what practitioners, such as the Chinese and other
>   Buddhist-influenced and Confucian-influenced societies, as well as the
>   African and European cultures see themselves as doing. This is
>   consistent with the meaning of the word veneration in English, that is
>   great respect or reverence caused by the dignity, wisdom, or
>   dedication of a person.

So apparently "ancestor veneration" may be a more PC or neutral-sounding word. You should take this with a grain of salt though, as I'm not sure whether the ideas expressed in the Wikipedia article are drawn from some established field of study like anthropology, or just one person's preferences (most of the citations in this passage are just to general-purpose dictionaries).

"Deadolatry" is not a word that I've ever heard before, and it sounds funny to me. I'd advise against using it. Deadrat's ["necrolatry"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/297543/77227) sounds better. To me, words like this that are based on "idolatry" have a definite negative connotation (which may well be what you want). The [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/necrolatry) define it as

> Worship of or excessive reverence for the dead

Comment: The Arab invaders were not ancestors of the people in that region, nor the saints in most cases were ancestors of the people being fooled into the worshiping them.

Comment: @Arjang: oh, that's a very good point. In that case "veneration of the dead"  and "necrolatry" both apply.

Answer (score -2):

The word that comes to mind for me is:

**martyr**
*noun*
a person who is killed because of their religious or other beliefs.

Or:

**consecrate**
*verb*
make or declare (something, typically a church) sacred; dedicate formally to a religious or divine purpose.

Answer (score -2):

**Reliquary** is probably the word... If you're talking about the container, including the bone(s).

**Venerate** is the verb you're looking for, probably. They were forcing the natives to worship the remains of their dead, as a way of oppressing them. These invaders were demanding that the natives *venerate* the *relics* of their (the invaders') dead.

For philosophical reasons, it seems to me **necrolatry** is not correct. I don't think it brings to mind the religious dominance that is being forced on the natives.